# Magento 1.9.1 strange behavior with layered navigation

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, layered-navigation, ajax

I am having this strange problem with a magento installation 1.9.1.

After template changed and nothing else my previous extension for layered navigation manadev layered navigation has a strange behavior with ajax loading. When I hit a category and choose a filter with few products everything works fine. But I have some filters with more than 1000 products each.I have magento default loading up 30 products. When you hit one of these filters it tries to load all the products in same ignoring the setting of 30 products.

So when I hit a filter or category with 2000 products I get a page with 2000 products loading one by. This kills my server and of course isn't working.

I tried everything I know but still all products from database are pulled together instead of getting them by portions (items per page).

When I turn off ajax everything is working fine. I use Varnish,Apache,APC,Memcached. I see no error at all except in frontend layered navigation page ESI processing not enabled but this is because we have caches off for development.

So for some reason ajax magento default number of products.

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.My theme implemented rel=prev/rel=next feature and this implementation doesn't work well with AJAX. So it is disabled as manadev extension brings compatible implementation of the same feature.

/public_html/app/etc/modules/GoMage_Navigation.xml_ (module disabled)
/public_html/app/code/local/TypoStores/TypoLogancee/Model/Observer.php (line 63 "return;" added)